# Golang setCookie() failed after template Execute()

Tags: templates, go, setcookie

As a beginner of GO, I've got a situation as following:

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("/template/login.tpl")

err = t.Execute(w, nil)         //if executed before SetCookie

http.SetCookie（...）          //failed, browser received nothing
```

If the sequence is changed, to `SetCookie` first, it'll work.

My plan was to `ParseForm()` username and password in `login.tpl`, if success, a `sessionID` would be sent by `SetCookie`. But now `SetCookie()` must be placed before `login.tpl` is `Executed`, which also makes `ParseForm()` run before `login.tpl` is executed :

```
r.ParseForm( )                          //ParseForm() works even before template is executed

email := r.FormValue("email")
pass := r.FormValue("pass")

var loginPass = checkLogin(email, pass) //verify username and password

if loginPass == true {                  //if correct

    cookie1 := http.Cookie{Name: "test", Value: "testvalue", Path: "/", MaxAge: 86400}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie1)         //setCookie works

    fmt.Println("Login success: ", email)

} else {                                //if incorrect username or pass

    fmt.Println("Please login: ", email)

}

t, err := template.ParseFiles("/template/login.tpl")
err = t.Execute(w, nil)                 //now template execution is here, also works
```

But why it should be written like this? Please anyone give me some advice! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error tied to the HTTP protocol working: the cookie is sent in a header of the HTTP respo7nse, which cannot be changed after the body start being sent.

So, when you do the `t.Execute(w, nil)` call, you start writing the body of the response and thus cannot add cookies afterwards.

This is the exact same reason why in PHP the `session_start()` call must be the very first instruction of the page, even before any whitespace.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thank you very very much.